# Perl Net::Bluetooth module

Tags: perl, bluetooth, cpan

I was looking for a Perl Bluetooth CPAN module. The only one that I could find was [Net::Bluetooth](http://search.cpan.org/~addutko/Net-Bluetooth/Bluetooth.pm). The last time it was updated was in 2007. For Windows installation, it needs Service Pack 2 installed and also the Microsoft Platform SDK. When I looked for them, it seems those SDKs are now obsolete and new Windows SDKs have been issued. I even tried the latest SDK (available for and on XP) after modifying the makefile as it suggested. That did not work either.

Is there any other Perl Bluetooth module that I can use that work on Windows XP/7?

Comment: Net::Bluetooth was last updated in 2014 and seems to be actively maintained. What's the problem you had with the new Windows SDKs?

Comment: I asked this question on Jun 6, 2014 and 6 months down the line, lo and behold, on Dec 1, 2014, version 0.41 came out, about 8 years after the release of 0.40. I have moved on, but thank you whoever started StackExchange!